# Dealing with parameters with white spaces in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to hit my API Gateway endpoint, but the path parameter includes a whitespace. How is this dealt with on the AWS end? Do I need to use `encodeURI` or does AWS handle it?

Currently I'm trying to grab data from DynamoDB using an address. Let's just say the address is `123 Abc St.` 
DynamoDB has my address stored as `123 Abc St.` - should I have changed it to `123%20Abc%20St.` and stored it as such? My API endpoint is `https://123abc.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/test/${address}`. Am I able to just pass the string `123 Abc St.` into my request?

Here's a sample request:

```
let getInfo = async (address) => {
  let { data: { Item } } = await axios.get(`https://123abc.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/test/${address}`)
  return Item
}
```

Currently when I run this, it doesn't return anything - I'm assuming it's because the request encodes it and my DB doesn't match with the parameter. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose 2 changes.

1. Move the Address to the body instead of the query string
2. Pass the string as a json string {"Address":"123 Abc St."}

Comment: What makes this better practice? When would I use a query string?